# Scraping data uri image

Tags: python, web-scraping, uri, scrape

I would like to scrape images from a webpage, the problem is the images are included in the source code as Data URI. How do I save them to a file?
(I need to access URI images only from specific scraped Data URI codes)

Comment: Do you mean to simply download an image given a URI? In that case, it is quite easy with modules from the standard library like [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, I cant see anything about this on the urllib2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The image/string is in base64 encoding (even stated in the URI itself!).  All you have to do is decode it, then write it to a file.

```
imageContents = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQSEhUUE"
myfile = open("image.jpg","w")
myfile.write(imageContents.decode("base64"))
myfile.close()
```

Comment: @user2521892: in this case, you should accept (and upvote) this answer (click the green tick).